# Spark Read files with special characters in Filename

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

While trying to reproduce XML parsing from this Databricks workshop uploaded on [Github](https://github.com/databricks-industry-solutions/hls-interop-workshop-jan23/blob/main/file.py), I'm not able to read the files in the download folder with accented (special) characters.

```
mkdir -p /dbfs/user/hive/warehouse/hls_cms_source.db/raw_files/synthea_mass
wget  https://synthetichealth.github.io/synthea-sample-data/downloads/synthea_sample_data_ccda_sep2019.zip -O ./synthea_sample_data_ccda_sep2019.zip 
unzip ./synthea_sample_data_ccda_sep2019.zip -d /dbfs/user/hive/warehouse/hls_cms_source.db/raw_files/synthea_mass/
```

This is probably because the path in the `spark.read` method is treated a regex string. How do I deal with this situation where the folder containing the XMLs have special characters in the filenames?

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
df = (
  spark.read.format('xml')
   .option("rowTag", "ClinicalDocument")
   .load('/user/hive/warehouse/hls_cms_source.db/raw_files/synthea_mass/ccda/')
)
```

The below file `Amalia471_Magaña874_3912696a-0aef-492e-83ef-468262b82966.xml` exists in the directory, however an error is generated complaining that the file does not exist:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 43 in stage 251.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 43.3 in stage 251.0 (TID 494) (10.139.64.6 executor 0): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /4842022074360943/user/hive/warehouse/hls_cms_source.db/raw_files/synthea_mass/ccda/Amalia471_Magaña874_3912696a-0aef-492e-83ef-468262b82966.xml
```

I'm using Apache Spark 3.2.1 on Databricks with DBR 10.4 LTS.